# "navigator service failed" error when deploying an AIR app to Blackberry Playbook

Tags: blackberry-playbook

Occasionally (but not always), when I deploy a debug build of an Adobe AIR app to a Blackberry Playbook (not the simulator), I get this error:

> Deployment Failed: Sending Install request...
>
> Info: Action: Install
>
> Info: File size: 2567343
>
> Info: Installing ...
>
> Info: Processing 2567343 bytes
>
> actual_dname::
>
> actual_id::
>
> actual_version::
>
> result::failure 500 /pps/system/navigator/control: navigator service failed

Unfortunately, it seems once I get this error, the only way to get around it is to restart the Playbook.

Anyone have any ideas have to avoid it?

I'm using Flash Builder Burrito on Mac OS X 10.6.7 with Blackberry SDK 1.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Navigator has crashed, and does not auto-restart, you would get that message and would indeed have to reboot to resolve the issue.  The system is not 100% reliable yet, so sometimes the System Tray or Navigator do crash and, so far, I've not noticed that they ever restart automatically.  Unless this is happening to you consistently in response to some action, I think your best bet for now is to wait for another update and hope that improves the situation.  If it does happen often, please post a question in the [Tablet OS SDK for Adobe AIR developer support forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Tablet-OS-SDK-for-Adobe-AIR/bd-p/tablet) to see if others have similar problems and together we can figure out how to reproduce it and file a bug report in the issue tracker.

You can confirm that the Navigator has crashed (I believe) by checking the bottom-swipe or side-swipe gestures, or just sliding around the icons on the home page.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't yet noticed a pattern why it crashes, but if I do I'll be sure to post question/bug in the forum.